# Select SUM multiply field for another field in different tables and this is equal

Tags: mysql

I explain through the example:

First table is products:

```
id|price|
1   30
```

Second table is warehouse:

```
id|id_product|amount|sell_price|
1       1       1        50
```

I will want SUM of multiply amount (warehouse table) * price (products table) where id (warehouse table) = id (products table)

```
$result_sum_ricavo = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT SUM(total_sum) FROM (p.prezzo * w.quantita as total_sum FROM prodotti p JOIN storico_magazzino w on p.id = w.id_collo AND w.causale='consegna' AND w.tipo='prodotto' AND w.importo_documento>0)");
$row_sum_ricavo = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_sum_ricavo); 
$guadagno = $row_sum_ricavo["total_sum"];
```

I have this error:

> mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean
>   given in

Comment: **I will want SUM of multiply amount (warehouse table) * price (products table) where id (warehouse table) = id (products table)**
Can you please explain this ? it is confusing @snakom23

Comment: what i understand is, you want sum of sell_price column from warehouse table and want to join products table and want all columns from it where warehouse table id_product = products table id

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
 SUM(total_sum)
FROM (
    SELECT p.price * w.amount as total sum
    FROM products p JOIN warehouse w on p.id = w.id
)
```